# Emacs - Path to Python interpreter

Tags: python, microsoft-windows, path

I've got python 3.6 in this directory:

```
D:\Python36
```

How can I set in .emacs path to python 3.6 interpreter?

Comment: Set that path for what? A guess is that you want to be able to invoke the external Python interpreter from Emacs. If so, it sounds like you just need to  ensure that it is reachable from your `Path` environment variable. That's not really an Emacs question. It seems you are on MS Windows. Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables, and update variable `Path` (or add the var if not there).

Comment: Please do not post the same question to StackOverflow and SE.emacs. Pick one or the other. Please delete one of the posts. Thx.

Comment: Thx for answer. I want to use Python 3.6 interpreter, something like this: (setq py-python-command "/usr/local/bin/python2.3")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("d:/Python36/")))
```

Comment: Where shall one write this? Isn't `exec-path` too generic?

Answer (score 4):

`python-shell-interpreter` is the variable you are looking for. You can set it using

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "D:\Python36")
```

Add this to your `.emacs` and reload python process.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it gives me error: Specified program for new process is a directory. I'm using elpy.

Comment: You should set path to executable like `D:\Python36\python`.

Comment: Now I've got this error :spawning child process invalid argument

Comment: Use forward slashes instead: `D:/Python36/python`. Backslash has a special meaning in Emacs, so if you want to use them, you have to escape them first (with, incidentally, a backslash) like so: `C:\\Python36\\python`. As you can see, it's easier to just use forward slashes instead.